# Bitcoin RawTransaction Json - what do all the variables mean

Tags: bitcoind

The below is the response we get. could someone please explain what each element is.

type RawTransaction struct {    Blockhash     string    BlockTS       uint32 json:"blocktime"    Confirmations int    Hex           string    Locktime      int    TXTS          uint32 json:"time"    TXID          string    Version       int    Vin           []struct {        ScriptSig struct {            Asm string            Hex string        }        Seqeuence int64        TXID      string        Vout      int    }    Vout []struct {        N            int        ScriptPubKey struct {            Addresses []string            Asm       string            Hex       string            ReqSigs   int            Type      string        }        Value Amount    } }

Comment: Maybe you should add a little bit more layout to your question.

Answer (score 1):

the transaction has inputs and outputs. the inputs describe the previous bitcoins being spent in this transaction and the outputs describe the address(es) to send these bitcoins to. you can view transactions for any block using blockexplorer.com. for example, [here is the simplified data for block 728](http://blockexplorer.com/b/728), and [here is the data for this same block converted from the blockchain into json format](http://blockexplorer.com/rawblock/00000000d14f2e97678951ad004d6699babd27e07ca722c46b30dc24c67eed7a).

for a good explanation of what each of these elements inside the transaction means, i recommend [this article](http://www.michaelnielsen.org/ddi/how-the-bitcoin-protocol-actually-works/).